# ChartSeries Horizontal Lines on TA

Tags: lines, quantmod, technical-indicator, horizontal-line

I wanted to add horizonal lines to the addRSI function that can be included in a ChartSeries chart.

When I call

```
getSymbols("VELO.CO")
p <- na.omit(VELO.CO)

name <- ""
chartSeries(p,name = 'Price Development of Asset - Date top-right')
chartSeries(p,subset = fivemonths,name = 'OBV, RSI, MACD Chart, and 50 & 200 
day EMA')
addOBV(col='white')
addRSI()
addMACD()
addBBands()
```

This gives me a nice chart with all the indicators included above. However, I was wondering if it'd be possible to add horizontal lines on the 70 and 30 levels of the RSI part of the chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
chart_Series(p,name = 'Price Development of Asset - Date top-right')

add_RSI()
```

You can use the 'new' quantmod plotting functions and get 30/70 lines automatically. Note the underscores in the functions.